# Android: using one Firebase ChildEventListener through my app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm looking for a way to listen to a particular location in my database in every activity using one `ChildEventListener`.

I have a shopping app, and I need to listen to the user's order status through the app to show alerts and save data locally.

***I had 2 ideas in mind:***

1. I thought about attaching and detaching the listener in `OnResume()`
   and `OnPause()` of every `Activity`, but the code will be duplicated in 
   every `Activity` since it does the same job.
2. I thought about attaching one listener to the `MainActivity`, then send
   broadcasts to other activities, but this failed due to `MainActivity`    being destroyed

--

What is the best practice for listening to one node and keep app synchronized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem in Firebase when using multiple listeners, even if it's the same listener. As long as you remove the listener according to the life-cycle of your activities, Firebase will handle almost perfectly the listeners.

Your class should look like this:

```
public class HelperClass extends Application {
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    public static verifyStatus() {
        databaseReference.addChildEventListener() /* ... */
    }
}
```

You need to remove the listener accordingly to the life-cycle of your activity. If you have added the listener in `onStart` you have to remove it in `onStop`. If you have added the listener in `onResume` you have to remove it in `onPause`. If you have added the listener in `onCreate` you have to remove it in `onDestroy`. But remember onDestroy is not always called.

Hope it helps.

Comment: You're right, but I'm aiming to centralize the work, so it's easy to modify the code later.

Comment: In this case you can create a `HelperClass` in which you can create a method that can be reused in every activity you need.

Comment: That was simple... Sounds like an idea, but wouldn't there be a delay if I'm creating listeners in each activity?

Comment: Now, there will be now delays because each listener will be treated separately. Remember, Firebase it's a Real-time database.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I needed to hear, any recommendation regarding life-cycle?  will `onPause()` and `onResume()` do the job perfectly?

Comment: No. You need to remove the listener accordingly to the life-cycle of your activity. If you have added the listener in `onStart` you have to remove it in `onStop`. If you have added the listener in `onResume` you have to remove it in `onPause`. If you have added the listener in `onCreate` you have to remove it in `onDestroy`. But remember `onDestroy` is not always called. Best solution are `onPause()` and `onResume()`. I also edited my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how to use this `HelperClass`, do I call `verifyStatus` in `onResume()` of every activity?

Comment: You call verifyStatus() wherever you need in every activity.

Comment: And where do I remove the listener?

Comment: You need to create another method which removes the listener,. You can call it `public static void removeListener() {...}`.  And you need to call it acordingly to your activity life-cycle. Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way create a **class** and inside **class** create the **method** that you want like that:

```
public class firebaseutils {

public static void check(){

    }

}
```

And call this **class** where you want, like that:

```
firebaseutils.check();
```

Answer (score 0):

recently I solved a same problem. So, make a handler class of the ChildEventListener and its has a single instance like FirebaseDatabase, FirebaseAuth and others Firebase services. That class is the same this snippet:

```
public class ShopHandler implements ChildEventListener {

    private static ShopHandler current = null;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    private ShopHandler() {}

    public synchronized static void attach() {
        if (current = null) {
            current = new ShopHandler();
            databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("data/yournode");
            databaseReference.addChildEventListener(this);
        }
    }

    public syncrhonized static void detach() {
         // remove listeners and set current as null
    }
    // implements all methods about ChildEventListener

}
```